# Почему "библия", а не "вивлия"?

Tags: этимология, история

Как правило, в словах греческого п происхождения, присутствующих и в русском и в западных языках имеет место соответствие русской "в" с латинским "b" (*варвар-barbar, Вавилон-Babylon* и пр.)

Вопрос: Почему в слове "библия", по всей видимости известному восточным славянам, как минимум, с  века Х, пишется "б", а не "в"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что слово "библия" заимствовано нами не с греческого,  а с латинского, и не в X веке, а гораздо позднее (по Фасмеру впервые зафиксировано в 1499 году).

Первоначально Библию называли "кънигы", затем Писание. Нынешнее название появилось уже под западным влиянием. Поэтому "в" и нету.

Несколько другая судьба у "библиотеки", которую ещё в XVIII веке называли вивлиофикой (см. "Древняя российская вивлиофика" Н. И  Новикова), но затем греческий вариант был вытеснен латинским.

Answer (score 1):

Именно потому, что не "с века X", а гораздо раньше, по крайней мере если отсчитывать от времени создания большинства греческих источников.
Б перешло только в словах, заимствованных славянам в поздний византийский период.
На более раннем этапе Б сохранялось. Это было справедливым и для письменных источников. 
Ко всему прочему могло сказаться и влияние слов, испытавших сильное романское влияние (не знаю, имело ли последнее место в нашем случае, но могло). 
Аналогично - библиотека.

Comment: Извините, а можете указать источник. Просто Ваша версия кардинально расходится с версией Марка Иза, а найти источников подтверждающих Вашу версию мне самостоятельно не удалось.

Comment: Только сейчас увидел. 
А что, собственно, "расходится"? 
Я говорю об исторических изменениях в греческом языке. 
"Библия" попало в европейские через латынь в тот момент когда буква бета читалась как "Бэ". Во времена Византии она уже стала "витой" и читаться кау "Вэ".  
Остальное - детали.